# Proper flashing of sheathing to gutters/roof when resheathing exterior

Tags: gutters, flashing, sheathing

Currently in the process of resheathing a small area of my house. Removed vinyl siding, foam sheet insulation, rotted out wooden siding, and asphalt paper (in that order). Replacing all with ZipSystem once I'm finished repairing some structural deficits caused by water/termite damage. I believe all the water was entering through a leaky roof at some point, which was replaced about four years ago (before I bought the house)[image]

What's the proper way to flash the top side of the sheathing with the existing gutters and framing? Do I need to remove the gutters? Every how-to I've found shows eaves that extend well beyond the walls, and the sheathing sitting up against soffit.